# how to attach this jquery method to all control inside grid view

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have one grid view which have drop down list inside update panel. i just want to all drop down inside this grid view behaviour like images + text (Binded images with drop down list). here images are successfully bind. but here all controls that may have take effect not rendered properly.

here is my jquery code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.dd.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        try {
            $("#<%=DDL_Column_List.ClientID %>").msDropDown();
            $("#<%=DDL_StatusList1.ClientID %>").msDropDown();//Grid view Drop Down List 1
            $("#<%=DDL_GroupList1.ClientID %>").msDropDown();//Grid view Drop Down List 2
            $("#<%=drp_title.ClientID %>").msDropDown();
            $("#<%=DDL_StatusList.ClientID %>").msDropDown();
            $("#<%=DDL_GroupList.ClientID %>").msDropDown();
            $("#<%=DDL_CountryNames.ClientID %>").msDropDown();
            $("#<%=DDL_StateNames.ClientID %>").msDropDown();
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e.message);
        }
    });
</script>
```

how ever this result only last row of grid view drop down list getting effect.

i just want to get all control rendered with this jquery function. Is there way to append this jquery function at grid view RowDataBind, RowCreated so it's renders properly.

Comment: So your gridview renders these dropdowns to every row it generates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you want to add that effect to every dropdownlist (select-element in html) then you could do for example:

```
$(function() {
    $(".myGridviewClass select").msDropDown();
});
```

Comment: how ever this effect getting disable when one of drop down list selected Index Changed event fired.

Comment: Does it have autopostback enabled? Then it will post the whole page to the server and reload the page. In which case you need to run that script again.

Comment: ya auto post back enabled. can u have i idea how i run again this script.

Comment: Well it should run every time the page is loaded if the script-block is on the page. If nothing is happening try to see if the script is there or not after the postback.

Comment: It's there after postback but it's getting normal after auto post back.

Comment: I have no of this kind of drop down list and they all have same issues. they all are renders properly when first page load. how ever when selectedIndex changed has been fires then it's getting normal.

Comment: What changes after the postback? That must be the key here.

Comment: the script remains there after post back. But drop down getting normal. can we write this method inside drop down internal method.

Comment: It should work, you need to figure out what changes from the first page load and after the postback. I cannot help you with that. See why the script is either not running or the jquery selector is not selecting right elements, or you dont have all required jquery(or other) plugins loaded in the page. Good luck!